# how to combine element in tuple or list accordingly python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a few tuples look like this. I would like to combine all the word in the same sentence.

```
('1.txt','sentence 1.1','city')
('1.txt','sentence 1.1','apple')
('1.txt','sentence 1.1','ok')
('1.txt','sentence 1.2','go')
('1.txt','sentence 1.2','home')
('1.txt','sentence 1.2','city')
('2.txt','sentence 2.1','sign')
('2.txt','sentence 2.1','tree')
('2.txt','sentence 2.1','cat')
('2.txt','sentence 2.2','good')
('2.txt','sentence 2.2','image')
```

how to combine the word according to the sentences for example:

```
('1.txt','sentence 1.1','city apple ok')
('1.txt','sentence 1.2','go home city')
('2.txt','sentence 2.1','sign tree cat')
('2.txt','sentence 2.2','good image')
```

or maybe in this way as list or dictionary

```
['1.txt','sentence 1.1',['city','apple','ok']]
['1.txt','sentence 1.2',['go','home','city']]
['2.txt','sentence 2.1',['sign', 'tree', 'cat']]
['2.txt','sentence 2.2',['good', 'image']]
```

if i would like to convert to dictionary , how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your input data, it seems like the words are keyed against a combination of the first and second items (indices 0 and 1) of the tuple.

You can build a dictionary mapping this item combination to words, and do some post-processing to reformat the data into the structure you want.

Here's a procedural, O(n) approach.

```
import collections

sentences = collections.defaultdict(list)
for file_name, sentence_id, word in input_data:
    sentences[(file_name, sentence_id)].append(word)

# sentences is now formatted like {('1.txt', 'sentence 1.1'): ['city', 'apple', 'go']}

for key, val in sentences.items():
    print list(key) + [val]
    # ['1.txt', 'sentence 1.1', ['city', 'apple', 'go']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `groupby` with the first two elements of each tuple as the key, assuming your list of tuples has already been sorted by the first two elements before hand:

```
from itertools import groupby
[[k[0], k[1], [i[2] for i in g]] for k, g in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[:2])]

#[['1.txt', 'sentence 1.1', ['city', 'apple', 'ok']],
# ['1.txt', 'sentence 1.2', ['go', 'home', 'city']],
# ['2.txt', 'sentence 2.1', ['sign', 'tree', 'cat']],
# ['2.txt', 'sentence 2.2', ['good', 'image']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
l=[]
l.append(('1.txt','sentence 1.1','city'))
l.append(('1.txt','sentence 1.1','apple'))
l.append( ('1.txt','sentence 1.1','ok') )
l.append( ('1.txt','sentence 1.2','go') )
l.append( ('1.txt','sentence 1.2','home') )
l.append( ('1.txt','sentence 1.2','city') )
l.append( ('2.txt','sentence 2.1','sign') )
l.append( ('2.txt','sentence 2.1','tree') )
l.append( ('2.txt','sentence 2.1','cat') )
l.append( ('2.txt','sentence 2.2','good') )
l.append( ('2.txt','sentence 2.2','image') )

d={}
for i in l:
    myKey=i[0]+" "+i[1]
    if myKey in d:
        d[myKey].append(i[2])
    else:
        d[myKey]=[]

ans=[]
for k in d:
    v=k.split(" ")
    ans.append([v[0],''.join(v[1]+" "+v[2]),d[k]])

print sorted(ans)
```